# linear functors commute with finite direct sums (in R-mod)

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm working on Exercise 8.16 from http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/syl11f.html.  In particular:

> Let F : ((R-mod)) → ((R-mod)) be a linear functor. Show that F always preserves finite direct sums. ...

The solution provided says:

> The first assertion follows immediately from the characterization of
>   finite direct sum in terms of maps (4.15), since F preserves the stated relations. ...

Unfortunately I can't discern anything from (4.15) [which I think is an incorrect link] or anything from its surroundings.  I feel like I'm missing something simple. I don't see any way to relate F(direct sum) to direct-sum(F).

Comment: What's your definition of linear functor?

Comment: Exercise (4.15) in [these notes](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/11Nts-2up.pdf) on the linked homepage definitely is the correct thing to look at. See also Zhen Lin's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/175103/5363).

Comment: @t.b.: thanks, I get it now.  I didn't realize the relevance of 4.15, but Zhen's answer makes it clean.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: that the functor induces an R-linear map from the hom-sets.