# What does an additive, mono-preserving functor have to do to become left exact?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, functors

Consider an additive functor $F \colon C → D$ of abelian categories preserving monos. As Martin has demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406602/42242), $F$ may not be left exact.

If $F$ even preserves kernels, $F$ is left exact. But for a functor of abelian categories, preserving kernels is strictly stronger than preserving monos. Are there other additional criterions, *not* strictly stronger than preservering monos, that would make such an additive, mono-preserving functor left exact?

Comment: An additive functor is left exact if and only if it preserves kernel. See [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+functor) or Iversen's cohomology of sheaves section 7.