# Right/Left-exactness in Abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, functors

All definitions I found say that a functor $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ is right-exact, if for every short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$
gives an exact sequence
$$F(A) \rightarrow F(B) \rightarrow F(C) \rightarrow 0.$$

Somehow I imagine to remember, that it is sufficient to require that any surjection $B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is mapped to a surjection $F(B) \rightarrow F(C) \rightarrow 0$, though I was neither able to prove it, nor did I find any reference. So it appears to me that this is wrong.

I would like to see a proof, or a counterexample for the claim that $F$ is right-exact if and only if it maps surjections to surjections.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think Zhen Li's answer applies to this question (it is not a functor between abelian categories). However, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406602/88262) answer of Martin Brandenburg does give an example of an additive functor between abelian categories that preserves epimorphisms but is not right exact.